# Select 100K+ records quickly

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

I need to select some 100k+ records from a SQL table and do some processing and then do a bulk insert to another table. I am using SQLBulkCopy to to do the bulk insert which runs quickly. For getting the 100k+ records, I am currently using DataReader.

Problem: Sometimes I am getting a timeout error in DataReader. I have increased the timeout to some managable number.

Is there anything like SQLBulkCopy for selecting records in a bulk batch?

Thanks!
Bala

Comment: Why do you not do the processing in teh Database, or even, just get the result set in chunks/pages?

Comment: Bala can you show us the way you use the DataReader in the code?

Answer (score 4):

It sound like you should do all your processing inside sql server. Or split data into chunks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i need to do some processing in XML data in .net side. i know we can do xml processing in SQL too but it is currently quite unmanageable in SQL side...

Comment: You can process them one by one. Open IReader, read, process, save. Until done.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx):

> **Note**
>
> No special optimization techniques exist for bulk-export operations. These operations simply select the data from the source table by using a SELECT statement.

However, on that same page, it mentions the `bcp` utlity can "bulk export" data from SQL Server to a file.

I suggest you try your query with bcp, and see if it's significantly faster. If it's not, I'd give up and try fiddling with your batch sizes, or look harder at moving the processing into SQL Server.